# Lazy Logical Replication - wlr.replicate error

Tags: monetdb

I am attempting to setup LLR on MonetDB. Starting the master (named monet-db-0-tenant) works fine, but when I attempt to clone a replica (named monet-db-1-tenant) using wlr.replicate, I receive the error: "Timestamp (monet-db-0-tenant) has incorrect format"

Example:

```
sql>CALL wlr.replicate('monet-db-0-tenant');
Timestamp (monet-db-0-tenant) has incorrect format
```

Note: I am in an mclient session on the replica database issuing this call to wlr.replicate.

Appreciate any guidance as to why this error might be occuring.

Comment: Lazy Logical Replication is a PoC feature. The MonetDB dev. team is still seeking partner (companies) that would help harden it out for general use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the source code, I did find where the wlr.master can be designated instead of providing it in the call to wlr.replicate. So, it appears the documentation should be updated to reflect a call to wlr.master.